# Is Firebase meant to only be used with iOS and Android?

Tags: firebase

I've just started using Firebase to create a web app.

More and more I get the feeling that Firebase is targeting mobile app developers, not web. Yes, they have a Web SDK, but there is so much that is only available for iOS / Android, such as:

- Analytics
- Notifications
- Remote Config
- Adwords
- Test Lab

Anyone care to shed some light?

Comment: Some Firebase features are indeed only available for iOS and Android. If you need those features on web, you'll indeed have to look elsewhere. In that case I'd also recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But aside from that, there is not a lot anyone can answer here - I vote to close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, basically `Google Analytics` was not made for tracking mobile analytics as it is web centric. `Firebase` started their analytics development around the mobile platform and then `Google` acquired it. Everything in the mobile is event based, this is the driving force for `Firebase` analytics.

So, if you are using a web application it is better to use the [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) which is web centric to get the clear and comprehensive web based analytics data.

Comment: Not to mention their taglines (september 2018): "Firebase helps mobile app teams succeed." "A comprehensive mobile development platform"

Comment: GA4 (which replaces all previous GA versions) is also event-based.